# What is the password salt in database and how should I use it with codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, encryption

I was working on the new membership project. And when I looking at the database design there is a password_salt field , which is VARCHAR(20). In my previous project I just encrypt the password with md5, it is not secure .

```
 $save['password'] = md5($this->input->post('password'));
```

I found some code to generate a salt , it seems to be just generate a random string, but what is the suitable size, is it sufficient to use VARCHAR(20)?

```
protected function _create_salt()
{
    $this->CI->load->helper('string');
    return sha1(random_string('alnum', 20));
}
```

Also, It would be highly appreciate if there is code example of

```
1) using salt to validate
2) using salt to hash the password so that it can save to database
```

Thanks.

Comment: Must Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords?rq=1

Comment: would be nice if there is some codeigniter example

Comment: The framework is irrelevant, there's no CodeIgniter-specific example.

Comment: @user782104 would be nice if you would show the CI code where you want to use the salt.

Comment: sha1 returns 40 characters, if you want to store it, you're probably looking for CHAR(40) instead of VARCHAR(40) since you'll always end-up with the same length.